# Change sprite frame in Craftyjs

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

How do I manually set the sprite from frame 0 to frame 1?

```
//Load assets
Crafty.sprite("assets/img/q.png", {
qd1 : [ 0, 0, 17, 16 ],
qd2 : [ 0, 17, 17, 16 ]
});

var a=Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, SpriteAnimation, qd1").attr({x : 355, y : 225});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the sprite used from the spritesheet via [`Sprite.sprite()`](http://craftyjs.com/api/Sprite.html#-sprite).
So in your case, to change the 1st sprite to the 2nd sprite in the second frame:

```
Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, qd1")
      .attr({x : 355, y : 225})
      .one("EnterFrame", function() {
          this.sprite(0, 17, 17, 16);
      });
```

Following is a snippet that demonstrates a constantly changing sprite. Notice the alternative notation for [`Crafty.sprite`](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-sprite.html) is used, which frees your mind to think in terms of tile coordinates, rather than pixel coordinates.

```js
Crafty.init();
Crafty.background('white');

// define spritesheet, each tile spans 60x60 px, 9 sprites in one row
Crafty.sprite(60, "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/images/spritesheet-2x.png", {
  first_sprite : [ 0, 0 ]
});

Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, first_sprite")
      .attr({x : 0, y : 0, idx : 0})
      .bind("EnterFrame", function(frameData) {
          if (frameData.frame % 100 === 0) // trigger roughly every 2 seconds
            this.sprite(++this.idx % 9, 0); // cycle through the 9 available sprites
      });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crafty/0.6.3/crafty-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have found my own solution using selector.

Comment: @ProybP please post your solution so others can see it too if they have same problem!